# How can LD_LIBRARY_PATH be changed within CMake?

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have a local shared library which is not in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
I want to run my executable, but since it cannot find the shared library in the system folders, it outputs "error while loading shared libraries".

A possible fix for this is to export a new LD_LIBRARY_PATH containing the local library folder.

How can I export automatically this environment variable within CMake?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your shared lib is not build in the same CMake project of your executable, you can use the CMake rpath handling like this:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

When you will run `make install`, CMake will automatically set the runtime path of your executable to your shared library.

If your shared library is built in the same CMake project, use this:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "/usr/local/lib")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

In this case you must add yourself the directory where your shared library will be installed to the runtime path.

For more information, you can read [CMake rpath handling](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling)

Answer (score 19):

You can set the runtime shared library search path using the `-rpath` linker option:

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS 
          "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib")
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use this solution:

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

Remembter to set the RPATH before defining the targets in your CMake-File. So this instruction have to be before `add_executable()` or `add_library()` is called, otherwise it has no effect.