# Set linker search path for build in CMake

Tags: linux, linker, cmake, executable

It seems this question has been asked very often before but none of the solutions seem to apply in my case.

I'm in a CMake/Linux environment and have to run an executable binary during the **build** step (`protoc` in particular).

This binary needs a library but it's **not installed** (and cannot be) in the in the standard directories like `/usr`, so the library cannot be found.

Unfortunately I cannot manipulate the `protoc` call because it's embedded in a 3rd party script.

I can now set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before every `make` or set it system wide but this is very inconvenient especially when it comes to IDEs in which the build takes place or distributed build scenarios with continuous build environments.

I tried to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` via

```
set(ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} "/path/to/library/dir")
```

but this seems to have no effect during the build step.

So my question is: can I set a library search path in CMake which is used during the build?

Comment: Can this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30455909/ help you?

Comment: unfortunately not because both library and executable are being built somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe, found a way: try adding to your `Cmake` script: `execute_process(COMMAND export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/library/dir:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH")` Hope, `Cmake` will start your 3rd party script in subshell/current shell - then `export` would affect it.

Comment: `can I set a library search path in CMake which is used during the build?` - If linker call is **not controlled by CMake**, then the only way to get proper library search path is to set corresponded environment variable. Setting environment variable inside CMake via `set()` doesn't affect *build* step. It may be possible to set environment with calling the 3d-party script, but it is dependent from the way how you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SET(ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} "/path/to/library/dir:$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}")
```

---

I also used this dirty trick to temporary change some environment variables:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/library/dir:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" cmake ...
```

After execution of this line `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not changed in the current shell.

Also, I do not find it bad to change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before invoking `cmake`:
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...`

It won't change anything system-wide, but it would be used for your current shell, current build process. The same holds for CI builds. You can save the variable and restore it after `cmake` invocation:

```
MY_LD=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...
cmake...
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MY_LD
```

Comment: I wrote this in my question - did I misunderstand you? :)

Comment: Note, I added `$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` to the right part. :)

Comment: Oh, and try BIG symbols `SET`. The biggest symbols you have ;)

Comment: Well, CMake comands are case insensitive and - I think I also said this - I cannot set an environment variable before running `make` because the `make` step takes place in environments I don't have easy access to. So I have to change my environment *inside* CMake and it has to apply not only to the configure but to the build step as well.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to do it *inside* Cmake if `SET` affects only *configure* stage. But I suggest using 2 ways of modifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead (in the same line with `cmake` and before `cmake`). It was convenient to me, but not to you. Sorry, afraid, it was all that I could suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently run into a somewhat similar problem.
My solution was to incorporate sourcing a file that set the appropriate environment into every command.
For example, this custom command:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT some_output
    COMMAND some_command
    ARGS some_args
    DEPENDS some_dependencies
    COMMENT "Running some_command some_args to produce some_output"
    )
```

Would become:

```
set(my_some_command_with_environment "source my_environment_script.sh && some_command")
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT some_output
    COMMAND bash
    ARGS -c "${my_some_command_with_environment} some_args"
    DEPENDS some_dependencies
    COMMENT "Running some_command some_args to produce some_output"
    VERBATIM
    )
```

Obviously, this has some disadvantages:

- It relies on a bash shell being available.
- It sources the environment script for every command invocation (performance issue) and you will have to change all invocations of commands that rely on that environment variables.
- It changes the normal syntax of having the command follow COMMAND and the arguments follow ARGS, as now the 'real' command is part of the ARGS.

My CMake-Fu has proven insufficient to find a syntactically nicer way of doing this, but maybe somebody can comment a nicer way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for an executable provided by a third party library. The binary was linked against a library not provided by the distribution but the required library was included in the libs directory of the third party library.

So running `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/thirdparty/lib /path/to/thirdparty/bin/executable` worked. But the package config script didn't set up the executable to search `/path/to/thirdparty/lib` for the runtime dependent so CMake would complain when CMake tried to run the executable.

I got around this by configuring a bootstrap script and replacing the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property with the configured bootstrapping script.

_thirdpartyExe.in

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=@_thirdpartyLibs@ @_thirdpartyExe_LOCATION@ "$@"
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(ThirdPartyLib)
get_target_property(_component ThirdPartyLib::component LOCATION)
get_filename_component(_thirdpartyLibs ${_component} DIRECTORY)
get_target_property(_thirdpartyExe_LOCATION ThirdPartyLib::exe IMPORTED_LOCATION)
configure_file(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} _thirdpartyExe.in
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/thirdpartyExeWrapper @ONLY
)
set_target_properties(ThirdPartyLib::exe PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/thirdpartyExeWrapper)
```

Honestly I view this as a hack and temporary stop gap until I fix the third party library itself. But as far as I've tried this seems to work on all the IDE's I've thrown at it, Eclipse, VSCode, Ninja, QtCreator, ... etc